# MySQL multiple SubQueries on same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I got a table **votes** that indicates me if a user voted for a specific movie. It also shows me how many movies a user has voted for.

```
 id_film | id_user | voting
----------------------------
   1     |    1    |    7
   1     |   33    |    5
   3     |    1    |    9
   4     |    7    |    7
   4     |    2    |    8
   4     |    1    |    6
   6     |    1    |    6
  ...    |   ...   |   ...
```

I want to get a list of id_film's which are related to id_user's in this way:

1. Get all **id_film's** from a specific id_user like

   SELECT id_film FROM votes WHERE id_user = 1
2. Grab every id_user which is related

   SELECT DISTINCT v.user FROM votes v WHERE id_film IN ( **id_film's** )
3. Then SELECT **id_film's** FROM votes v WHERE user IN ( "user list from previous query" )  except **id_film's** from first query.

This was my first attempt:

```
SELECT id_film, film.title, film.originaltitle, COUNT(*)
FROM votes v
INNER JOIN film ON v.id_film = film.id
WHERE user IN
(
   SELECT DISTINCT v.user
   FROM votes v
   WHERE id_film IN
   (
       SELECT id_film
       FROM votes v
       WHERE user = 1
   )
)
AND
id_film NOT IN
(
   SELECT id_film
   FROM votes v
   WHERE user = 1
)
GROUP BY id_film
```

It doesn't work. MySQL took too long for a result and I restarted XAMPP.

So I tried another SELECT, this time with **JOINS**:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT v.id_film AS vFilm, v1.user AS v1User, v2.id_film AS v2Film
FROM  votes v
LEFT  OUTER  JOIN votes v1 ON v1.id_film = v.id_film
LEFT  OUTER  JOIN votes v2 ON v1.user = v2.user
WHERE v.user = 1
AND v1.user != 1
AND v2.id_film NOT 
IN 
(
   SELECT id_film
   FROM votes
   WHERE user = 1
)
GROUP  BY v2.id_film
```

Also doesn't work, but when I tried it without the **NOT IN** condition in the end it works! (*It took appr. 13 sec.*) :-(

Here is the working query.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT v2.id_film AS v2Film
    FROM  votes v
    LEFT  OUTER  JOIN votes v1 ON v1.id_film = v.id_film
    LEFT  OUTER  JOIN votes v2 ON v1.user = v2.user
    WHERE v.user = 1
    AND v1.user != 1
```

With Output

```
 v2Film
---------
   1
  13
  14
  58
   4
  ...
```

But this query doesn't except **id_film's** from first query.
Because I know that user 1 already voted for id_film 1.

So, am I totally wrong with my logic or is my code too complex for this?

Comment: So a list of all movies that those that voted on the same movies as you did have voted on?

Comment: Exactly. If somebody also voted for a movie you've voted for, show all his other movies he has voted.

Comment: Paste aall your tables and expected O/P. so that we can help you out in achieving your result.